# Cannot get my internet to connect

Tags: internet

I own an HP ProBook 4520s laptop which is dual-booted with Windows 8 Pro and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I use a wired PPPoE internet connection, which works fine in Windows. But for the last few days I can't use it in Ubuntu. When I start the connection from terminal it doesn't show any errors, but I can't load any webpages in Firefox. Using the 'plog' command, I get the following messages at the end:

Remote message: Login incorrect
PAP authentication failed
Connection terminated

My Ethernet connection works fine in both Windows and Ubuntu. Can anyone please help me figure out what the problem is?

Comment: I don't have a PPPoE connection myself, so I won't post this as an answer :) have you double checked your PPPoE credentials ? You may also find this helpfull on the official 12.04 LTS documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/powerpc/pppoe.html

Answer (score 1):

check your network connection setting and make sure that VPN connection is not enabled

Comment: Can you include a answer with instructions on how to do that? Leaving a [half-answer as a comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments) can often cause more harm than good. Take a time and add all the information that could be useful, as a step by step guide or add screenshoots, etc. Thanks!

Comment: I have checked my network connections. There are no VPN connections enabled.